# Angular 4 services local json file shows undefined results

Tags: json, angular

I have created a service named User.service.ts and inside i have written this code:

```
getContactDetials(){
        return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + 'assets/data/contact-details.json')
        .map(response => response.json());
    }
```

And when i am trying to access the content using this service in contact.component.ts then strangely i am not able to see any results. For further investigation i have logged in the console then the results shows as 'undefined'.

The code for my contact.component.ts is:

```
contactDetails: any[];
  constructor(private _userService: UserService) { 
    console.log('Contact Tab is pressed!!');
  }    
ngOnInit() {
         this._userService.getContactDetials()
         .subscribe(data => this.contactDetails = data.results);
         console.log(this.contactDetails);
      }
```

The template where i am binding the data is :

```
<tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of contactDetails">
                  <td>{{ item.field_email }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.field_first_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.field_last_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.field_mobile }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.field_department }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.field_contact_email_address }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.field_mobile_1 }}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
```

But unfortunately i am not able to display the data in the table. Can anybody help me? What is the mistake i made?

Thanks

Comment: can you log the result of your http call in your service?

Comment: Yes when i log the data then it shows in the console properly. .map(data => {
            data.json();
            console.log("I CAN SEE DATA HERE: ", data.json());
        });

Comment: if the 'data.results' shows undefined, so what does it show when u log only 'data'?

Comment: do you see that as a `string` or is it `json` object. It would help if you are able to update your question with your `log`.

Comment: Thank you Sameh awad.. It worked now!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: One more thing i am getting this error pp/components/contact/contact.component.ts (17,25): Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Comment: Since you are not sharing any information from your console.logs.So we are shooting in the dark here. Is the results now defined as an array?

Answer (score 0):

If 'data.results' shows undefined, then may if you try to log only 'data' would give you some insights to what you are receiving on the other end.